# xquery - join with conditions

Tags: xquery

I am trying build html table rows from a  list of linked numbers, querying for the presence of the corresponding release number in an online xml file and, if available, adding extra sibling element information.

This is the online xml file: http://www.sec.gov/about/docket/sec-docket-2013.xml

The imlit.xml list file looks like:

```
<litigation>

[...]

<h2>Affiliated Transactions/Joint Transactions</h2>

   <ul>
    <li><a href="/litigation/admin/2014/ia-3762.pdf">IA-3762</a></li>
    <li><a href="/litigation/admin/2013/ia-3654.pdf">IA-3654</a></li>
    <li><a href="/litigation/admin/2013/34-69425.pdf">34-69425</a></li>
</ul>

[...]

</ligitation>
```

I got this to work in Basex:

```
for $x in doc("C:\bob\dev\xquery\imlit.xml")/litigation/ul/li,
    $y in
doc("http://www.sec.gov/about/docket/sec-docket-2013.xml")/secDocket/releaseItem[releaseNumber
= $x/a]
return (<tr> <td> {$x/a} </td> <td> {data($y/date)} </td> 
<td> {data($y/subjects/subject)} </td> </tr>,  '&#xa;')
```

and I get:

```
[...]

<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="/litigation/admin/2013/ia-3740.pdf" target="_blank">IA-3740</a>
  </td>
  <td>2013-12-17</td>
  <td>Dappah, Frank</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="/litigation/admin/2013/ia-3729.pdf" target="_blank">IA-3729</a>
  </td>
  <td>2013-12-02</td>
  <td>Dushek, Charles J. Dushek, Charles S.</td>
</tr>

[...]
```

However, I'd like to insert "placeholder" table rows if there is no match and also include the h2. So I'd like to get something like the following. In the first tr "placeholder" row, "34-71069" from imlit.xml doesn't match against sec-docket-2013.xml

```
<h2>Compliance Programs</h2>

<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="/litigation/admin/2013/34-71069.pdf" target="_blank">34-71069</a>
  </td>
  <td>insert date</td>
  <td>insert respondent</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="/litigation/admin/2013/34-71069.pdf" target="_blank">34-71069</a>
  </td>
  <td>2013-12-12</td>
  <td>Wayne, Mark M.</td>
</tr>
```

I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
for $x in doc("c:\bob\dev\xquery\imlit.xml")/litigation,
    $y in
doc("http://www.sec.gov/about/docket/sec-docket-2013.xml")/secDocket/releaseItem
return
if ($x/h2)
then $x/h2
else if ($x/ul/li/a = $y/releaseNumber)
then <tr> <td> {$x/ul/li/a} </td> <td> {data($y/date)} </td> 
<td> {data($y/subjects/subject)} </td> </tr>
else <tr> <td> {$x/ul/li/a} </td> <td> insert date </td> 
<td> insert respondent </td>     </tr>
```

I seem to get an endless recursion of $x/h2. I am not understanding how the conditional statement should work and how the query is processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build the join all on your own, just fetch the necessary information from the website for each turn. I opted for creating a dummy result if there is no document available instead of applying the case distinction in the `return` clause to somewhat decouple logic and presentation.

```
let $sec := doc("http://www.sec.gov/about/docket/sec-docket-2013.xml")
for $litigation in doc("C:\bob\dev\xquery\imlit.xml")/litigation/ul/li
(: Fetch matching document if available, otherwise create dummy result :)
let $document := $sec/secDocket/releaseItem[releaseNumber = $litigation/a]
let $document :=
  if ($document)
  then $document
  else
    <releaseItem>
      <date>insert date</date>
      <subjects>
        <subject>insert subject</subject>
      </subjects>
    </releaseItem>
return (
  <tr>
    <td>{$litigation/a}</td>
    <td>{data($document/date)}</td> 
    <td>{data($document/subjects/subject)}</td>
  </tr>,
  '&#xa;'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer is to just add "allowing empty" in your $y for clause. That way, if there are no matches, there will still be an output node, but with $y bound to the empty sequence.

```
for $x in doc("C:\bob\dev\xquery\imlit.xml")/litigation/ul/li,
    $y allowing empty in doc("http://www.sec.gov/about/docket/sec-docket-2013.xml")
    /secDocket/releaseItem[releaseNumber = $x/a]
return (
    <tr>
        <td> {$x/a} </td>
        <td> {data($y/date)} </td> 
        <td> {data($y/subjects/subject)} </td>
    </tr>,
    '&#xa;')
```

You can test this here (just with the doc call adapted to Zorba): http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/PFV2cuMlMvqyUipmtIN3IQZCzJk=

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works well when there are matches in the online docket file, but when there are no matches, the empty cells have unexpected syntax: <tr>
  <td>
    <a href="/litigation/admin/2014/33-9521.pdf" target="_blank">33-9521</a>
  </td>
  <td/>
  <td/>
</tr>

Comment: I think it's because the default serialization format is XML. In your case, you probably want to use the HTML serialization format instead, which will output the tags the HTML way. How to do it depends on the engine, even though XQuery provides a standard way to do it in the prolog that an engine may or may not implement.